# How does C++ maintain streams under the hood?

Tags: c++, iostream, stringstream

I am working on a program where I tried to use stringstream and became a little confused about how actually streams work under the hood.

Consider this for example:

```
    char * dataset = new char[3000];
    stringstream buff;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 3000; ++i)
        if (dataset[i] != 32)
            buff.put(dataset[i]);
    delete[] dataset;
    string temp = buff.str();
```

Another way of doing this would be:

```
    char * dataset = new char[3000];

    //Count the number of spaces
    unsigned int unwanted = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 3000; ++i)
        if (dataset[i] == 32)
            ++unwanted;

    //Copy all characters other than spaces
    char * temp = new char[3000 - unwanted];
    for (unsigned int i = 0, j = 0; i < 3000 - unwanted; ++j)
        if (dataset[j] != 32)
            temp[i++] = dataset[j];
    delete[] dataset;
    dataset = temp;
```

Now the confusion here is this:

How can streams keep on accepting the characters and not care about the size? I mean I just keep on putting a character and it keeps on adding to the stream buffer. My intuition also tells me that streams probably don't maintain a string or a similar data structure under the hood that they can expand if they hit the size limit.

So what exactly is driving these streams? I mean what kind of data structure is working under these streams. And do we even have a stream size limit or can we just keep on adding without caring about exceeding the size?

Lastly, from the above two methods, which one would be a better one. I tried profiling both for a 147K characters array and the second one seemed to be better working.

Comment: Do you know how `std::string`/`std::vector` work?  Same thing here since a `stringstream` is implemented via a `std::string`.

Comment: Why wouldn't a `stringstream` maintain a `std::string` under the hood? It already contains the code to reallocate when it needs to.

Comment: Streams maintain a streambuf. Stringstreams maintain a [stringbuf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf). "Typical implementations of std::basic_stringbuf hold an object of type std::basic_string or equivalent resizeable sequence container directly as a data member ..."

Comment: `std::basic_stringstring` uses a `std::basic_stringbuf` as its internal buffer. `std::stringbuf` uses a `std::string` for the character sequence.

Comment: FWIW, If you want a string with all the spaces removed you can just do `dataset.erase(std::remove(dataset.begin(), dataset.end(), ' '), dataset.end());`

Comment: So in essence, using a stringstream is no better than using the 2nd method I pasted and possibly worse, since if the stream hits the size, it resizes and copies the data to a possibly new data structure. While the 2nd method just shrinks it once and copies the required data?

Comment: Yeah, a stringstream is total overkill here and wont give you any benefit.

Comment: `std::stringstream` is all kinds of inefficient. They are nice to use when speed is not a factor though.

Comment: @ParkerQueen The main benefit of `stringstream` is when you want more complex formatting, you can use all the special values that work with `<<`

Comment: And of course, it's useful when you have generic output code, and you simply want to redirect it to a string.